# Create simple http request from chromium code

Tags: c++, rest, networking, get, chromium

I want to collect some statistics of my chromium build and for that purpose I want to send some very simple data (for example just a string) with simple GET or POST request for example in browser startup stage in Launch browser function: [link to code](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:chrome/browser/ui/startup/startup_browser_creator.cc;l=344?originalUrl=https:%2F%2Fcs.chromium.org%2F) and in other similar places.

There is a way to write it on bare C++ with sockets and bytes but to be honest it's bad way I think.

I tried to read [the documentation](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/network-stack) but without examples it's quite difficult to write code. To find example I found some usages in tests like: [link to the code](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:net/quic/quic_stream_factory_test.cc;l=538;drc=22387b44ff173d263b434889d394cea90368ab06;bpv=0;bpt=1?originalUrl=https:%2F%2Fcs.chromium.org%2F) but still it not so easy to get really necessary part from this for very simple purpose: just to send "hello world" to the server.

Can anyone help with simple example how to use chromium api to make this simple request?

- How to initialize QuickStreamRequest (or I need other Request)?
- Where to get QuickStreamFactory?
- Which parameters to put into Request method?
- How to put request data ("hello world") into request?

Very simple example will bee cool :)

Comment: You need `network::URLLoader`.

Comment: - What do I need to put as parameters to constructor (what is instance)?

- How to run loader->Open (i.e. in some special thread)?

- How to initialise UrlRequestInfo?

- How to put most simple on result callback into loader->Open?

Comment: Seems you confused with `pp::URLLoader`. Look at `URLLoderTest:Load`.

Comment: How to create NetworkContextClient in my case (not test)? What is context() in URLLoader constructor?